# How to pass a parameter to a javascript function that populates a div from a page model to its Razor Page?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to use Braintree's payment DropinUI, and configuring it requires sending a generated token
to a javascript function in my page. I have the following markup in my Razor Page:

```
<div id="dropin-container"></div>
<button id="submit-button">Request payment method</button>
<script>
    function configureBraintreeClient(clientToken) {
        var button = document.querySelector('#submit-button');

        braintree.dropin.create({
            authorization: clientToken,
            container: '#dropin-container'
        }, function (createErr, instance) {
            button.addEventListener('click', function () {
                instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (requestPaymentMethodErr, payload) {
                    // Submit payload.nonce to your server
                });
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

The div #dropin-container is populated by the result of the function configureBraintreeClient. So, I need to pass in a clientToken when the page loads.

My page model to generate a client token:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IJSRuntime _jsRuntime;

        public IndexModel(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
        {
            _jsRuntime = jsRuntime;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            // Create gateway
            var gateway = new BraintreeGateway
            {
                Environment = Environment.SANDBOX,
                MerchantId = "xxxxxxx",
                PublicKey = "xxxxxxx",
                PrivateKey = "xxxxxxx"
            };

            var clientToken = gateway.ClientToken.Generate();

            JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(_jsRuntime, "configureBraintreeClient", clientToken);

            // Not sure if this is needed, doesn't work with return type of 
            // void and this line removed either.
            Page();
        }
    }
```

This does not work. The div is never populated.

**I can insert a client token directly into the markup and it runs perfectly**, so it has something to do with passing the client token
to the page from the page model. Should I not be using the JSRuntime extension?

I've tried setting the client token as a model property and inserting it in the function with razor syntax like `authorization: @Model.ClientToken`
but it doesn't work.

I've tried to dig around to understand the page life cycle better but nothing I have found has helped me figure out this issue.

I see no errors in the developer console of my browser or in Visual Studio, but I don't know a lot about debugging javascript in ASP .NET Core.

What's the proper way to pass a parameter into a javascript function that updates a div like this?

Comment: i am trying to do the same. could you share with me your working files?

Comment: Hi @BarryMSIH, it's been over a year but the key for me was the single quotes around the reference to the model property. See the second code block in the accepted answer. Everything else can be gotten from Braintree's documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For we do not have `merchant ID`,`Public key` and`Private key`,be sure that you have generated the correct token,then you could try this:

1.IndexModel():

```
private readonly IJSRuntime _jsRuntime;

public IndexModel(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
{
    _jsRuntime = jsRuntime;
}

[BindProperty]
public string clientToken { get; set; }

public void OnGet()
{
    // Create gateway
    var gateway = new BraintreeGateway
    {
        Environment = Braintree.Environment.SANDBOX,
        MerchantId = "xxxxxxx",
        PublicKey = "xxxxxxx",
        PrivateKey = "xxxxxxx"
    };

    clientToken = gateway.ClientToken.Generate();

    JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(_jsRuntime, "configureBraintreeClient", clientToken);
}
```

2.Razor Page(no need to use function):

```
<div id="dropin-container"></div>
<button id="submit-button">Request payment method</button>

<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.20.4/js/dropin.min.js">
</script>
    <script>
            var button = document.querySelector('#submit-button');
            braintree.dropin.create({
                authorization: '@Model.clientToken',
                container: '#dropin-container'
            }, function (createErr, instance) {
                button.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (requestPaymentMethodErr, payload) {
                        // Submit payload.nonce to your server
                    });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

3.Test(You could see that the token has filled into the js):
[image]
Reference:

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v3

> I can insert a client token directly into the markup and it runs perfectly, so it has something to do with passing the client token to the page from the page model. Should I not be using the JSRuntime extension?

For this,if you want to use client token,I suggest that you could refer to:
https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/tutorial-drop-in-node

For authorization,you could also use [tokenization key](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/authorization/tokenization-key/javascript/v3).